# Duplicate elements in DOM when running Selenium browser tests

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

This is a really weird one which I've never seen before and it's difficult to google.

We have a single page app which has internal tabs (not Chrome tabs, pure html simulated tabs in the app). We have end to end Selenium C# tests which run fine when using a single tab. We created some test which run with two html tabs open, and they failed. They failed because a modal with a Open button in it was duplicated & when the test went to click it, it clicked the original not the duplicated and threw an error. There should only ever be one instance of the modal and its components, in fact when you run it as a normal user thats exactly what happens. Here's the scenarios:

1. Running locally, as normal browser session, two application tabs open, open the modal dialog, one instance of the Open button in the DOM.
2. Running locally, debug run Selenium C# Visual Studio, two application tabs, open the modal dialog, two instances of the same open button in the DOM, test fails as code is looking for the 'first' one and error is 'another element will get the click'.

This is an Angular 4 SPA project - never seen anything like this before. There are elements in the DOM being duplicated depending on the browser mode. Has anyone else seen this?

Not sure if this is a problem with our app - which case why does it not do this when we run as a normal user? Or if its a problem with how we are launching Chrome from the test suite - we're not specifying any Chrome options when new'ing up a ChromeDriver instance.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML and code trials

Comment: It probably possible to solve with proper selectors. Please share html.

Answer (score 0):

'another element will get the click' doesn't mean that there is another element for the specified selector. It usually means that there is another element ON TOP of it (hiding it). I would recommend you creating screenshot right before and after the click and manually inspect if the element is indeed visible at that moment.
Also  check if the element you are selecting is not by accident 0,0 size, and when a user clicks, click is received by  a child or something like that